# Verben: was machen wir mit unserer Nase?

Tags: word-usage, big-list

Ich bin auf der Suche nach diversen Verben, die eine Aktion bezeichnen, die wir mit unserer Nase machen, wie z.B. das Verb *riechen*. Ich habe bereits Folgendes (www.duden.de) gefunden:

**schnüffeln**

1. (meist von Tieren) in kurzen, hörbaren Zügen durch die Nase die Luft einziehen, um einen Geruch wahrzunehmen
   (*Der Hund schnüffelt an jedem Laternenpfahl.*)
2. [aus Neugier] etwas, was einem anderen gehört, heimlich, ohne dazu berechtigt zu sein, durchsuchen, um sich über ihn zu informieren (*Er schnüffelte in meinen Unterlagen*.)

**schnuppern**

1. (meist von Tieren) in kurzen, hörbaren Zügen durch die Nase die Luft einziehen, um einen Geruch wahrzunehmen (*Der Hund schnupperte am Baum*.)
2. an einem Kurs teilnehmen (*Wir wollen beim Baseball nur mal schnuppern*.)

**schniefen** (beim Atmen, besonders wenn die Nase läuft) die Luft hörbar durch die Nase einziehen

Fallen Euch andere Verben ein (auch das, was man macht, wenn man sich Drogen in die Nase zieht)? Vielen Dank!

Comment: Suchst du auch Verben, die nicht unmittelbr mit Luftfluss zu tun haben bzw. bei denen die Nase eher die Rolle eines Objekts hat? (kratzen, putzen, popeln, ,,,)

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: wenn ich ehrlich bin, habe ich auch Verben und Ausdrücke wie „in der Nase bohren“ und „jemanden an der Nase herumführen“ mit notiert. I'll take everything you have, guys! =) Bin für jede Ergänzung hier dankbar!

Comment: Diese Frage riecht doch stark nach einem Community Wiki! - Bitte richte eines ein, damit wir hier nicht 17 einzelne Antworten kriegen.

Comment: Christian, was bedeutet "Community Wiki"? Off-topic?

Comment: @serena  - Das ist eine Form einer Antwort hier in diesem Forum, bei der beliebig viele Autoren in die gleiche Antwort hineinschreiben können. - Uh... vielleicht Denkfehler von mir: Vermutlich können nur Antwortgeber so was anlegen, nicht Fragensteller... komischerweise sehe ich den Link hier nicht. Wurde er vielleicht wegprogrammiert?

Comment: Sieht mir nach einem Kandidaten für das Tag *big-list* aus, das schon im Erläuterungstext als *off-topic*-gefährdet bezeichnet wird.

Comment: "an einem Kurs teilnehmen" - so, wie es hier steht, ist dies *keine* Bedeutung von "schnuppern". Beachte, dass der *Kurs* im Duden lediglich ein Beispiel ist; "schnuppern" beschränkt sich in diesem Sinn keineswegs auf Kurse und es geht auch gerade *nicht* um die reguläre Teilnahme. Eine passendere Umschreibung wäre mMn "probeweise an einer Gemeinschaftsaktivität teilnehmen".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because big list questions like this one are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Vielleicht kenne ich die Regeln dieser Webseite nicht, aber ich verstehe nicht ganz, warum würde man vorschlagen, dass die Frage geschlossen wird, wenn man sieht, dass es hier einem geholfen wird?!! Ist es etwa nicht der Zweck dieser Community?

Answer (score 3):

**sich eine blutige Nase holen (bei)** = mit etw. scheitern und dadurch schmerzhafte (auch fig.) Nachteile erleiden

**nach Nase** (entscheiden) = willkürlich, oder nach Sympathie

**jm gefällt js Nase nicht** = jemand ist dem anderen unsympathisch; typisch im Western: "Deine Nase gefällt mir nicht."

**eine Nase / ein Näschen haben für** = das Talent haben, eine Chance zu wittern

**jm eine Nasenlänge voraus sein** = s.o.

**die Nase (von etwas) (gestrichen) voll haben** = einer Sache überdrüssig sein

**die Nase rümpfen (über)** = sich über etwas erhaben fühlen, herabblicken auf

**jm läuft die Nase** = er hat Schnupfen

**(gehen Sie) immer der Nase nach** = immer geradeaus

**alle naselang stoßen auf / passieren** = alle paar Meter, alle paar Minnuten

**nasalieren** = durch die Nase sprechen

**jn an der Nase herumführen** = ihn anschwindeln, täuschen

Das ist, was mir auf die Schnelle einfällt. Ansonsten einfach mal im Duden schauen:

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nase

und/oder bei dwds:

https://www.dwds.de/wb/Nase

oder bei Wortschatz Uni Leipzig:

https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl-public_2018&word=Nase

Dort kann man vor allem auch nach Wortzusammensetzungen suchen, indem man ins Suchfenster *nase** oder **nase* oder **nase** eingibt.

Außerdem gibt's noch Wiktionary und diverse weitere Wörterbücher. Darunter auch nicht schlecht, mit ein paar selteneren Verben wie 'schnobern' und 'flehmen':

https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/edit/11704

Ich finde, die Arbeit kann man sich schon selber machen, da kommen mit Sicherheit über 100 Sachen zusammen.

---

Grad fallen mir noch ein: **schnauben, trompeten**

---

Es gibt übrigens auch noch das hier:

> "Er legt mit seiner Nase auf"

Zu finden hier [hier](https://www.radiofm1.ch/musik/er-legt-mit-seiner-nase-auf-135063847). Es geht da um einen polnischen DJ.

Ansehen kann man sich das mal auf [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahhNmPkPwDU).

Und von Mozart erzählt man sich folgende Geschichte:

*Mozart hätte einst mit Haydn gewettet, er könne ein Klavierstück schreiben, das zwar er selbst, Mozart, spielen könne, nicht hingegen sein Gegenüber, Haydn. Haydn nahm die Wette an und spielte brav das technisch leichte Stück vom Blatt, bis er an eine Stelle kam, an der die linke Hand im tiefsten Bass und die rechte Hand auf den höchsten Tönen ganz rechts auf der Klaviatur beschäftigt war, und nun sollte aber laut der Partitur gleichzeitig ein einzelner Ton in der Mitte angeschlagen werden. Haydn soll vor Wut die Noten zerrissen und gesagt haben, dass diese Stelle im Stück unspielbar sei. Als nun Mozart an die Reihe kam und das Stück - das er natürlich auswendig kannte - vorspielte, spielte er jenen einsamen Ton: mit seiner* **Nase**.

Ich frage mich, wie da die Fingersatzbezifferung aussehen mag, wie man sie in guten Klavierpartituren findet.

Comment: besten Dank! mein Wortschatz wurde um einiges reicher! =) Eine Frage zu den Verben "nasalieren", "näseln" und "nuscheln": Bedeuten die Verben "näseln" und "nuscheln" das Gleiche? / Mein Wörterbuch sagt, dass "nasalieren" ein rein sprachwissenschaftlicher Terminus ist (aus dem Bereich der Phonetik). Stimmt das? Also wenn jmnd durch die Nase spricht, sagt man "er näselt/er nuschelt", aber nicht "er nasaliert"? Habe ich es richtig verstanden?

Comment: Nuscheln heißt *undeutlich sprechen*. Mit der Nase hat das nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 2):

Eindeutig:

- **schreiten**

Beleg:

> Auf seinen Nasen schreitet 
>   einher das Nasobem 
>   von seinem Kind begleitet, 
>  
>   es steht noch nicht im Brehm 
>   [...]
>
> (Christian Morgenstern)

Daneben:

- **näseln**

Das kann eine Lautbildungs-Dysfunktion beim Sprechen oder Singen meinen. Es kann aber wohl auch den "Nasengruß" bestimmter nördlich wohnender Kulturgemeinschaft meinen.

- **überall reinstecken**

"Steck doch nicht überall deine Nase rein!* = Kümmere dich nicht immer um Dinge, die dich nichts angehen.

- **eins auf die N. kriegen**

Umgangssprachlicher Ausdruck für: bei einer Aktivität von Dritten (meist unverwartet) grob darauf hingewiesen werden, dass diese die fragliche Aktivität eingestellt sehen möchten.

- **jemandem eine N. drehen**

Etwas veralteter Ausdruck für "jemanden verhöhen, jemanden veräppeln"

- **schneuzen**

Sich schneuzen / die Nase schneuzen / sich die Nase schneuzen = Ausatmen durch die Nase unter hohem Druck, um Fremdkörper und Sekrete aus dem Nasenluftkanal nach außen zu entfernen

- **putzen**

Sich die N. putzen: wie *schneuzen*, aber in zurückhaltenderer Weise (weniger laut, etc.)

- **jemandem eine N. voraus sein**

In einer Konkurrenzsituation einem Gegner zeitlich, inhaltlich oder kräftemäßig (leicht) überlegen sein.

- **auf die N. fallen**

Bei einer Unternehmung unerwartet scheitern

Comment: Rechts unter dem Eingabefeld für die Antwort lässt sich das Häkchen für *community wiki* setzen. Da du das aber nicht gemacht hast, füge doch - wenn du magst - noch *rümpfen* hinzu. Verdrehte Welt: die Nase läuft, die Füße riechen.

Comment: Man kann auch *die Nase hoch tragen*.

Comment: Christian, sei un amore! Viiielen Dank für die Mühe! =)

Comment: @Olafant  - Ach ja, rechts unterm Eingabefeld... da ist es ja. - Hab's jetzt eingeschaltet.

Answer (score 2):

niesen,

atmen, einatmen, ausatmen

rotzen,

popeln,

triefen,

schnuffeln

näseln

Answer (score 2):

https://www.dwds.de/wp?q=Nase&comp-method=diff&comp=&pos=2&minstat=0&minfreq=5&by=logDice&limit=49&view=table 
Siehe 2 Tabellen: "ist in Präpositionalgruppe"  und "ist Subjekt von"

Comment: Dan, vielen Dank für den Link! Großartig!